# How to control RGB lighting for Asus ROG laptop's built-in keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, asus, brightness, 20.04, keyboard-backlight

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for quite some time but I haven't managed to find any fixes.

I have an Asus ROG Strix G731GT laptop running a dual-boot of Windows 10 & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The laptop's built-in keyboard has RGB lightning.

The problem is that while on Windows I can easily control the lights using the Armoury Crate and Asus Aura apps from the Microsoft Store, I cannot manage to find an alternative to these programs for Linux.

Not even the key combinations (FN + arrow keys) that are used to control the RGB's brightness and pattern work.

Does anyone have a clue as to how I can control the RGB on my keyboard? All the solutions I have found online are for external keyboards, but I couldn't find anything related to the built-in keyboard.

(Note: In this case my keyboard's RGB *does* function, but I just can't change the color or the brightness of the RGB.)

Thanks!

EDIT: I have found a solution using https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to control the lights using a repository called 'rogauracore' (https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore). The command syntax is really easy and it works perfectly.

Comment: pamac install rogauracore-git worked perfectly

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: It did not work for me after Ubuntu installation, but with later updates, perfectly. Good to have the lights off during serious work!

Answer (score 1):

In your linux terminal paste the following commands (source- https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore):

```
sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev
VERSION=1.4
curl -LOs https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore/releases/download/$VERSION/rogauracore-$VERSION.tar.gz
tar xf rogauracore-$VERSION.tar.gz
cd rogauracore-$VERSION/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and then just run the command for your preferred colour, for eg:

```
sudo rogauracore single_static 0000ff
```

Hope it helps.

Note:

. Install g++ prior to running the ./configure command.

. It may happen that you have to wake up the keyboard, run `sudo rogauracore initialize_keyboard` for that and then try setting the colour.

Comment: What if after “sudo rogauracore initialize_keyboard“ it shows me message like “can’t find any device”?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me: https://github.com/legacyO7/TUF-Aurora

https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore didn't work for me.